HTTP Basic: Access denied out of the blue, only when using pip download poetry install works fine
I have a Gitlab shell runner set up on a RPi that is running some jobs in my pipeline.
From one day to the next, the job started failing due to not being able to correctly install a private Gitlab dependency.
Running command git clone --filter=blob:none --quiet https://gitlab.com/myprivaterepo.git /tmp/pip-download-ijy4m42d/myrepo
  remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied. If a password was provided for Git authentication, the password was incorrect or you're required to use a token instead of a password. If a token was provided, it was either incorrect, expired, or improperly scoped. See https://gitlab.com/help/topics/git/troubleshooting_git.md#error-on-git-fetch-http-basic-access-denied
  fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://gitlab.com/myprivaterepo.git/'
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

In the gitlab cicd settings, the repo that is being accessed has the correct job token permissions to allow the other repo to clone it using the CI_JOB_TOKEN. I am also setting  git config --global url."https://gitlab-ci-token:${CI_JOB_TOKEN}@gitlab.com/".insteadOf "https://gitlab.com/"
The odd thing is that when I manually try to do the steps on the gitlab runner, poetry install works correctly, it can clone the repo. It's when it tries to use pip download that it doesn't work.
I just don't understand how it was working, and then it stopped working despite no changes in the code.
I have tried clearing everything from the git config on the gitlab runner, with no better outcome.
There are no expired tokens, because we aren't using any, we are just using the CI_JOB_TOKEN, which is generated automatically.
I also went through the Gitlab release notes to try and see if something changed with the Job token permissions but didn't see anything.
